# Xcode IOKit builds well but makes no Build folder or driver

Tags: xcode, build, iokit

I am familiar with windows driver developing (WinDDK) but recently changed to Xcode for mac and now I am absolutely newbie in this field.
I am trying to make a sample project from Apple tutorial from here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html

I have added all settings and now it is turn to make kextlibs try but I can't find any Build folder or driver.
In fact when writing other programs in Xcode , I can run them successfully in simulator but never could make a .dmg file to use without the simulator. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a 'Products' group in your XCode project's file tree. It should contain your .kext bundle. If you right-click that after a successful build, you can select "Show in Finder". Unlike earlier versions, XCode 4 places build products in a folder somewhere under ~/Library/ - it's not exactly easy to find by hand.

Comment: Sorry but I really cant find it.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your project's navigator view? ⌘-Shift-4, then drag rectangle. Screenshot file will land on your desktop.

Comment: /Users/Augend/Desktop/Screen Shot 2012-08-22 at 4.04.44 PM.png

Comment: sorry,  the website doesnt allow new members to send images!

Comment: Thank you.  Finally I could resolve it.  It was a big help. I just needed to go to Product folder in Xcode . My mistake was searching it in Finder. I dont know why Apple is hiding such crucial data . Perhaps they think KGB data are found there !!!